# Doing binary subtraction using operations (without - )

Tags: binary

I know that I can perform multiplication via shifting and adding binary numbers. However I was wondering if I can also subtract with out using the minus sign.

The closest approach I can reach to is y + (~x + 1). However I don't know if its correct, plus are there any other ways?

Comment: Just use the subtraction operator. Every language supports it and it will be as fast as if not faster than any alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are referring to is a way of representing negative number in binary called two's complement. The two's complement is found by inverting all the bits and adding one. For example,

```
7 - 5 = 2

0111 - 0101 =   0010

0111 + 1011 = 1 0010
```

where the extra one is a carry.

There is also a method using one's complement where the bits are simply inverted, but this has the disadvantage of possibly creating a negative 0.

This is the way subtraction can implemented in hardware.